# Call NSObject type file with click event of button

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I want to create a class of NSObject type and then I want to create one button click here in this file and also perform some event with this button. After that, I want to call this file in my view with the click event of another button called "push me". What code should I write to call that NSObject type file?

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're asking. Can you add more details, or perhaps reword your question in some way?

Comment: suppose i have created one button in NsOject type class.and i want to call that file on click event of my nib file button push me means if  i will click on push me button then that class will be fired and one new button will be display on my main view.

Comment: Do you have code (even if it's broken) showing your attempt thus far? That should help illustrate exactly where you need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a ViewController with a nib file and the Custom Class(***derived from NSObject***) is named as **MyClass**. And in your custom class you have created and named the button as **myButton**. And **myButton** is defines as a ***property*** in the Custom Class. You can write a method which will be called on the **"push me"** button click. The code can look something like this.

```
-(IBAction)pushMeButtonClicked
{
   MyClass *myObj=[[MyClass alloc] init];
   [self.view addSubview:myObj.myButton];
}
```

The ***init*** method of the MyClass can be defined as:

```
-(id)init
{
    self=[super init];
    if(self)
    {
       myButton=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    }
}
```

And of course you need to set the ***frame*** for the button **myButton** as per your needs.